# blocks in views and refactor in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator, content-tag

I have notes attribute in Product model with text "something, something else".
In views I wanted see:

```
<div>
  <span>Something</span>
  <span>Something else</span>
</div>
```

Also I have working code, but I want refactor with decorator(draper) or maybe use helpers.

```
%div
  - product.notes.split(/,/).each do |e|
    %span= e.strip.capitalize
```

In decorator:

```
def notes_list
  model.notes.split(/,/).each do |e|
    h.content_tag(:span, e.strip.capitalize)
  end
end
```

In views:

```
%div
  = product.notes_list
```

(or analog in helpers:

```
  def notes_list(product)
    product.notes.split(/,/).each do |element|
      content_tag(:span, element.strip.capitalize)
    end
  end
```

call:

```
%div
  = notes_list(product)
```

)

But this returns

```
    <div>

 "  
                       ["something", " something else"]
                          "
    </div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: ` h.content_tag(:span, e.strip.capitalize)` what is the "h"?

Comment: decorator calls helper method  https://github.com/jcasimir/draper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your notes_list is returning `product.notes.split(/,/)`

Try

```
def notes_list(product)
  result = product.notes.split(/,/).inject([]) do |result, element|
    result << content_tag(:span, element.strip.mb_chars.capitalize)
  end
  result.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: Corrected, had forgotten to assign the return from inject.

Comment: result: <span>Something</span> <span>Something else</span>.   contant_tag includes into array how a string

Comment: added html_safe after join("\n") and all OK)

Comment: ... as long as you are confident that the notes are safe :). If not, you should probably sanitize them.